# How to print out an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so this is a code that should be able to print out an array and say how many times the numbers 0-9 were inputed through scanner, if a negative number is given, the point is to stop the program and print everything out, and as you can see this program is perfectly fine, and im able to print out the array with numbers an all, but Im wondering how can I print out my array as "x" instead of numbers?  lets say the number 5 were inputed 5 times it should print out this: "The number 5 appears xxxxx times, likewise if the number 1, is pressed 1time, it should print out "The number 1 appears x times. any tips/solutions on how I can do this? Thanks in advance. (edit idk why the stars icon disappear, but lets say I want x instead.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class q31{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(1 + ":" + "\t" + "Integer 0-9");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] a = new int [10]; 
        int counter=0;
        int input;
        input=keyboard.nextInt(); 
        boolean exit=true;

        while (exit==true) {
            counter++; 
            System.out.println((counter+1)+":" + "\t" + "Integer 0-9");
            if (input>-1 && input <10){ 
                a[input]++;
            }

            input=keyboard.nextInt();
            if(input<0) {
                exit=false; 
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("the number " + i + " appears " + a[i] + "times"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the number at position i in the array `a[i]` to control a loop. The loop can do a `System.out.print("x")` for each iteration.

Some code is below - I've left the implementation of the loop to you as I guess this may be homework.

```
System.out.print("the number " + i + " appears ");

//create loop
    System.out.print("x");
// end loop

System.out.println(" times");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
System.out.println("the number " + i + " appears " + a[i] + "times");
```

to

```
System.out.print("the number " + i + " appears ");
for(int n = 0; n < a[i]; n++)
    System.out.print("x");
System.out.println(" times");
```

Comment: Like I said, just change that one line to what I wrote. It uses a for loop to write 'x' to the console `a[i]` times